# Can I disable/uninstall OneDrive on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8

I gave OneDrive a go and stopped using it due to poor linux integration. Now I'm using a different cloud storage tool and have no need for that OneDrive icon on my desktop in Windows.

I can hide it, but it still attempts to sync everytime I log on, and it's "yet another icon" sitting in my list of hidden taskbar icons and yet another folder I never use whenever I open a file explorer window.

I've searched for this online but the only solutions I could find seem to involve applying [some sort of registry hack](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-skydrive-integration-windows-8-1).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just don't connect your local user to a Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 2):

Change from the current Microsoft Account to a local account.

**PC Settings>Accounts>Disconnect**.

Note that if you do so, the settings on your account eg Lock screen picture, apps etc will not be synced if you switch computers.

If you're just tired of seeing the icon at the panel and want to keep using your Microsoft Account, then you can just click on the arrow on the taskbar(bottom right), click **Customization**, then find the OneDrive logo and click **Hide Icon and Notifications**.

To stop syncing you can go to **Sync Settings** and for **Sync Your Settings On This PC** choose **Off**.

**Microsoft Account vs Local account**

**Microsoft account:**

•   You can use your @outlook.com or any email address and password to sign in to Windows 8.

•   When you sign in with a Microsoft account, your PC is connected to the cloud.

•   Your friends’ contact info and statuses are automatically up to date from your Hotmail, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and other accounts.

•   You can get to and share your photos, documents, and other files from SkyDrive, Facebook, Flickr, and other accounts without signing in to each one.

•   Your personal settings are synced to any PC running Windows 8 that you sign in to, including your themes, language preferences, browser favorites, and apps.

•   You can get apps in the Windows Store and use them on any PC running Windows 8 that you sign in to.

•   Easily reacquire your Metro style apps on multiple Windows 8 PCs. The app’s settings and last-used state persist across all your Windows 8 PCs.

•   You can associate the most commonly used Windows settings to your user account. In this way, the saved settings are available when you sign in to your account on any Windows 8 PC. So your PC will be set up just the way you are used to.

•   You can also save time with sign-in credentials, because now the same credentials are available for the different apps and websites you use and you can easily get back into them without having to enter credentials every time.

•   You can automatically sign in to apps and services that use Windows Live ID for authentication.

**Local account:**

•   You use a user name (and password if you want one) to sign in to Windows 8.

•   A local user account gives you access to only the PC it's on. You will need a separate user account created on each PC you use.

•   None of your settings will be synced between the PCs you use, and you won't get the benefits of connecting your PC to the cloud.

•   You will not be able to use any modern apps that use a Microsoft service that require you to be signed in to a Microsoft account.